# Не удается реализовать запрос с помощью группировки! Не выводится нужный результат

Tags: sql, sql-server

Условие даны 4 таблицы

```sql
Create table [dbo].[t_grie00_Pilots2]
(

ID_pil nvarchar(10) not NULL,
Surname varchar(50) not NULL,
AviaOtryad varchar(50) not NULL,
Hours_Limit int NULL,
Primary Key (ID_pil)

)
```

```sql
create table [dbo].[t_grie00_Navigators2]
(

ID_nav nvarchar(10) not NULL,
Surname varchar(50) not NULL
AviaOtryad varchar(50) not NULL,
Hours_Limit int NULL,
Primary Key (ID_nav)

)
```

```sql
create table [dbo].[t_grie00_Riese2]
(

ID_riese nvarchar(10) not NULL,
Destination_City varchar(50) not NULL,
Personal_Service varchar(50) not NULL,
Time_flights int NULL,
Complexity int NULL,
Primary Key (ID_riese)

)
```

```sql
create table [dbo].[t_grie00_Flights2]
(

ID_zap nvarchar(10) not NULL,
Month_Date varchar(50) not NULL,
Pilot nvarchar(10) not null, 
Navigator nvarchar(10) not null, 
Ries nvarchar(10) not NULL,
Numver_vylet int NULL,
Number_hours int NULL,
Primary Key (ID_zap)

)
```

**Данные по таблице также предоставлены**

Пилоты

```sql
(011, 'Lyapin', 'Nishegorodski', 50),
(012, 'Ivanov', 'Moscowski1', 48),
(013, 'Polivsev', 'Moscowski2', 32),
(014, 'Sviatov', 'Moscowski3', 49),
(015, 'Shybenkov', 'Volgogradski', 50);
```

Штурманы

```sql
(021, 'Sidelnikov', 'Moscowski1', 48),
(022, 'Bobylev', 'Moscowski2', 48),
(023, 'Samarin', 'Moscowski3', 50),
(024, 'Platonav', 'Nishegorodski', 49),
(025, 'Kylenkov', 'Volgogradski', 50),
(026, 'Ovchinnikov', 'S.-Peterbyrgski', 49);
```

Рейсы

```sql
(031, 'Moscow', 'Nishegorodski', 0, 1),
(032, 'Perm', 'Nishegorodski', 0, 3),
(033, 'Volgograd', 'Volgogradski', 0, 2),
(034, 'Habarovsk', 'Moscowski2', 0, 4),
(035, 'S.-Peterbyrg', 'Moscowski2', 0, 2),
(036, 'Ischevsk', 'Moscowski3', 0, 2),
(037, 'Myrmansk', 'Moscowski1', 0, 2);
```

Полеты

```sql
(12500, 'January', 011, 021, 034, 3, 12),
(12501, 'January', 011, 024, 033, 4, 8),
(12502, 'January', 013, 022, 037, 3, 6),
(12503, 'February', 012, 024, 033, 4, 8),
(12504, 'February', 014, 023, 033, 5, 10),
(12505, 'March', 011, 021, 033, 4, 8),
(12506, 'April', 011, 014, 032, 3, 9),
(12507, 'April', 012, 025, 037, 4, 8),
(12508, 'April', 015, 026, 034, 3, 12),
(12509, 'May', 012, 023, 034, 4, 16),
(12510, 'June', 015, 025, 031, 4, 4),
(12511, 'July', 011, 021, 034, 4, 16),
(12512, 'August', 011, 022, 032, 4, 12),
(12513, 'September', 015, 026, 037, 3, 6),
(12514, 'December', 011, 021, 031, 4, 4),
(12515, 'December', 012, 025, 035, 6, 12),
(12516, 'December', 011, 024, 034, 4, 16);
```

Нужно, используя средства группировки реализовать запросы, такие как:

--для каждого пилота вывести по месяцам названия городов, куда он летал более раза;

```
select   p.Surname,  Month_Date, r.Destination_City from [dbo].[t_grie00_Flights2] f
left join [dbo].[t_grie00_Pilots2] p on f.Pilot=p.ID_pil
left join [dbo].[t_grie00_Riese2] r on r.ID_riese = f.Ries
where Numver_vylet>1 
group by  p.Surname, Month_Date, r.Destination_City
--order by ID_pil
```

-- определить пилотов и месяца, в которых данный пилот налетал более 30 часов.

```
select Month_Date, Pilot, p.Surname  from [dbo].[t_grie00_Flights2] f
left join [dbo].[t_grie00_Pilots2] p on f.Pilot=p.ID_pil
left join [dbo].[t_grie00_Riese2] r on r.ID_riese=f.Ries
where f.Number_hours>30 
group by Month_Date, Pilot, p.Surname
```

Ни тот ни другой не выводит нужный результат.

Из первого я потом донже вывести для каждого рейса фамилии пилотов, на нем работавших ...

Во втором запросе по всей видимости нужно сравнить не каждое количество часов, а суммарно для каждого пилота.

**Товарищи,Требуется помощь!**

Comment: В первом запросе вряд ли Numver_vylet - это количество вылетов. Количество скорее всего получается как `count(*)`, значит надо убрать where и добавить `having count(*) > 1`

Comment: Во втором запросе соответственно надо получать и проверять сумму часов налета, т.е. видимо `sum(Number_hours)`, если конечно налет находиться в этом поле

Comment: *по месяцам названия городов, куда он летал более раза* Вообще или только за отчётный месяц?

Comment: Проверку надо производить после группировки и суммирования. Т.е. в HAVING, а не во WHERE.

Comment: @Akina в целом, т.е вообще

Comment: @Mike не сработал ваш вариант по первому запросу

Comment: Кто -нибудь может дать ответ верным запросом, пожалуйста?

Comment: *в целом, т.е вообще* Тогда только подзапрос. Ибо разные уровни группировки. Или оконный COUNT в CTE.

Comment: Что значит "не сработал" ? Что он выдал и что ожидалось ? А то видите, вопрос по разному может читаться. Я бы его понял как выдать в каждом месяце только те города в которые пилот именно в этом месяце летал несколько раз. Собственно having с группировкой именно так и работает. А если надо куда за любые месяцы, то как пишет выше Akina, нужен либо подзапрос, которые заранее получит нужные города для каждого пилота, либо группировать по месяцам, а потом на основе этого результата брать общее количество по всему пилоту